# Pachyderm WebObjects web application

Tags: java, mysql, web, webobjects

I can't register to soucerforge, for some spam problem, so I thought of trying in here. I did get to mailing list and post the same there but the project community is not very active (if there is any).

Web application is http://sourceforge.net/projects/pachyderm/files/pachyderm-3.0/

Problem is that it won't start.

Setup: Tomcat 7, MySQL 5.6.24
I can't get pass:

> "[-NOTIFY-] appWillLaunch"
>
> "** DirectToWeb could not find user.d2wmodel file. One will be created if you try to save changes."

in Pachy30T.log.

Mysql connection works (at least it looks like it), besides:

> "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc] is not bound in this Context".

Tables are created, but are empty. I thing this is connected to
"dbConnectURLGLOBAL" variable (see logs).

Also error:

> "OsidContextRegistry: unable to find OsidContext-OID.dat
>
> null
>
> OsidValueRegistry: unable to find OsidValue-OID.dat" , can be seen in tomcat7-stdout.2015-06-17.log

I can connect to the host, TC is running on port 80, but there is no response.
How long should one wait? I did delete the tables, and let it run for a night. All I got is "T E N  M I N U T E  T I M E R" message. In the below logs, that message is gone. Looks like I am very close:)

LOGS ARE HERE (LINK): https://db.tt/5m1sp8BD

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was no problem at all. I've just used the wrong link/URL to access the web app.
The correct one is http://hostname.com/pachyderm/WebObjects/pachyderm.woa